# Write the method secondHalf that returns the second half of an array. Cannot use shortcuts, only for loops

Tags: java, arrays

> Complete the method secondHalf that returns an array that is the second half of list. If the length of list is odd, second half return the smaller half of the list.

I am doing corrections for myself for a quiz that I had made a mistake on. An example output would be:

```
1,2,3,4 --> 3,4
1,2,3,4,5-->4,5
```

What I wrote for this method, which is half wrong according to my teacher, is:

```
public int [] secondHalf(int[]list)
{
   int []a = new int [list.length/2];
   for(int i =0;i<list.length;i++)
   {
       a[i]=list[list.length/2+i];
    }

    return a; 

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You method iterates over the entire `Array` passed and then copies the `list[list.length/2+k];` element over to the new `Array`. (I'm assuming `k` is meant to be `i` here.)

Not only will this lead to an `indexOutOfBoundsError`, this will return an `Array` with the same size as the `Array` passed in. You could solve this problem by looping until `a.length` (`for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++)`), but this will only work with `Array`'s of even size.

Instead you can use the built in method `Arrays.copyOfRange()`:

```
public int[] secondHalf(int[] arr) {
     return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, (arr.length+1)/2, arr.length);
}
```

Or with just loops:

```
public int[] secondHalf(int[] arr) { 
    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length/2];
    for(int i = (arr.length+1)/2, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        newArr[j++] = arr[i];
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Sample input and output:

```
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Output: [3, 4]

Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
Output: [4, 5]
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the comment but I cannot use copyOfRange in my code(no shortcuts unfortunately:( )

Comment: do u know how to do it if it's even and if it's odd?

Comment: because in the problem it says if it's odd, you have to return the smaller half of the array and if it's even then just return the second half.

Comment: oh, thanks! but do u know why the teacher included the odd part in the question? was he trying to trick us??

Comment: @YoLo No that is just a requirement that your teacher gave you

Comment: The 'hidden trick' that solves even/odd here, is adding 1 to  length and the implicit rounding downwards of the result of (length+1)/2 which happens due to making an int out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public int [] secondHalf(int[]list)
{
   int size = list.length % 2 == 0 ? list.length/2 : list.length/2 +1;  
   int []a = new int [size];
   int index = 0;
   for(int i = size;i<list.length;i++)
   {
       a[index]=list[i];
       index ++;
    }

    return a; 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that can solve your issue. I will post the method and then explain each section of the method:

```
public static Object[] secondHalf(Object[] array) {
    /*
     * This is a method that returns the second half of an array. If the Array is odd, it 
     * should return the smaller half of the Array. 
     */
    Object[] k = new Object[array.length / 2];
    int half = array.length / 2;
    int y = 0;

    for(int x= 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        if(half % 2 != 0) {
        if(x > half) {
            k[y] = array[x];
            y++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(x >= half) {
                k[y] = array[x];
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
    return k;

     }
 }
```

The first thing that you should do here is return and pass an Array of the Object datatype to your method. You did not specify in your code if an list of Integers (or the primitive int) will always be passed to the method as the Array. Just to be safe, I changed it to the Object datatype and we can use auto unboxing later on just in case you pass a different datatype to the method. Secondly, we can create a new Array Object in the code that will be half the length of the Array that you pass to the method. We will also create a variable called "y" that we can use to increment to the correct index of the Array that we are adding a value to from the "second half" of the Array that we pass to the method. Next we create a for loop and if the "half" variable is odd, we will add a variable to the index of the Array that we created (k) only if that index is greater than the half variable. We add that value to the y index of the Array k. We create an else statement just in case the length of k is even, and if so we only add a value if the index of the array that we are iterating through is >= half. Again, we add the value to the y index for k and then increment y. Below is how we call this method in the main method of your program:

```
Object[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondHalf(nums)));
```

And here is what your output would be:

```
[5, 6, 7]
```

As you can see, this code returns the "second  half" of your Array.